# Get text value from element when display:none

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Html code:

```
<asp:Label ID="LblCt" runat="server" Style="display:none" Text="">72</asp:Label>
```

I get `""` when I use with this codes:
**JQuery**: `$("#LblCt).text()`, `$("#LblCt).textContent`
**Asp.Net**: `LblCt.Text`

How can I get the text of the label?

I can't use CSS - `visibility:hidden`

**Update:**
The problem is because of `display:none`, when `Display:block` there is no problem.

Comment: Depending on your version of Web Forms, you might not actually have an element with that Id and will, instead, see that it has a mangled Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have invalid markup...

```
<asp:Label ID="LblCt" runat="server" Style="display:none" Text="">72</asp:Label>
```

should be:

```
<asp:Label ID="LblCt" runat="server" Style="display:none" Text="72"></asp:Label>
```

then to get the value with JQuery, you can do this.

```
$("#<%= LblCt.ClientId %>").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

**In JQuery**

to set:

```
$("#LblCt").text("new text");
```

to get:

```
var text = $("#LblCt").text();
```

**In Asp.Net**

Thanks GOD, i don't use ASP...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#LblCt).text()=""
```

This assumes that the id is `#LblCt`. In ASP.NET that would be the server side ID, you want the client side Id.

Try

```
$("#<%= LblCt.ClientId %>").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

even though this is ages ago, i think what you can also do is set your object id to be static using ClientIDMode="Static".
<asp:Label ClientIDMode="Static" ID="LblCt" runat="server" Style="display:none" Text="">72</asp:Label>

Unfortunately i still have to use

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).